# What is the best way to ask user if they would like to proceed to a new step after completing a wizard

Tags: wizard, confirmation

I have a 2 step wizard where at the end of successful completion of the wizard, an object is created.

Once the object is created, the user will need to take an extra step to actually use this object.

At the end of the wizard, I'd like to ask the user whether they want to just finish creating the object or if they want to take the next step. How should this be displayed to the user? Would a modal dialog be too intrusive and alarming?

Sample of what the wizard looks like.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1VlnM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose that there should be three things the user should know at the end of a guided task flow:

> 1. Whether his/her task was successfully completed, and what the results were.
> 2. Whether he/she can create multiple objects with the same wizard,
>      without leaving the create environment. Loop the create process.
> 3. Whether there are next steps that he can do with the created object. This step is usually optional and mostly these are launch points to different applications or different parts of same application.

[image]

So you can go with something like the wizard shown in the image above.

Hope this helps you!

Cheers, Nishant

Comment: You can't just answer with an image with no explanation of what the image is and why you're suggesting it. Can you provide more reasoning and description of what this image is and why it fits the problem outlined in the question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out JonW.. i was in a bit of hurry and thought of just posting the answer with the mock.

Comment: Thanks Nishant for your input. This does give me some ideas of what could work. 

If a user selects one of the optional checkboxes, is it expected or intuitive enouogh that they must click 'next steps action' to execute the next steps? Can they also select finish with a checkbox marked or would this void the user's checkbox selection?

Comment: Let me clear the thought process here: As i said these would be three different parts of the last step. The user gets used to clicking the next on previous steps, so they would assume the wizard to end with the finish button in the same place. We are also giving a different real estate for next steps, i have shown them as check boxes but these can well be links of individual action button depending on your need. Also closing the wizard on click of these actions on next steps is optional, it should be driven by whether the user in most cases would create just one object or go for many.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting it in a final confirmation screen where the user can see details of the object created and launch it as needed. The screen might look something like this

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmzFBw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This is very similar to the installation completion wizard screens which allow users to launch an application after installing it as shown below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just do the usual thing and use the checkbox? There's no need to depart from the standard and introduce a button.

Comment: @AndrewLeach we can do that but the issue I noticed with the checkbox is that its not very noticeable and the call to action button gives more direction about the potential next thing the user can do.

Comment: Great example of a similar interaction! For dialog wizards, it is common in Windows applications to use a checkbox. Is it common in website wizards as well? I cannot think of this being used widely, if at all.